# Is it a directed topological space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is the following a [d-space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+topological+space) (directed topological space)?

Consider a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology.

Let d-paths are paths lying inside a polygonal chain (in the plane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand what "lying inside a polygonal chain" means ( = with image contained in a [polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain)), the answer is yes:

- Every constant path does.
- Whether a path does, depends only on its *image* - so reparametrization is trivially satisfied.
- The concatenation of two paths which do, does.

These are the only aspects of the definition (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+topological+space#definition).